# How to use ternary operator with Array in php?

Tags: php

I want to use ternary operator with Array

Kindly check my code below

Below is my Dynamic Array

Array elements can Add or remove dynamically.

```
$cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");

<?=(isset(exist(cars[3]))'Exist Element Name'?'Toyota');?>
```

Instead of Toyota it will show last array position element. Here in this case cars[2]. Because cars[3] does not exist yet.

I am not able to do above line correctly. If Array element position is exist then it shows what is in the position like "FORD" if it will not exist then it will show last array position element.

I want this dynamically for all the position automatically. If they exist then show elements, if not exist then show last element.

Comment: You can use the null coalesce operator: `$cars[$index] ?? end($cars)`

Comment: @Raymond Nijland Thanks for the reply. But how to use this line in turnary operator?

Comment: @Raymond Nijland Can we do like this? <?=isset($cars[4]) ? $cars[$index] : end($cars);?>

Comment: I removed mine comments.. You try search the array on names like Volvo right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### PHP 7+

Forget the ternary operator and just use the null coalesce operator:

```
<?= $cars[$index] ?? end($cars) ?>
```

This says, use $cars[$index] if it's available, else default to end($cars), which is the last thing in the array.

### PHP 5

You can use the ternary operator:

```
<?= $cars[$index] ? $cars[$index] : end($cars) ?>
```

Or its shortcut form:

```
<?= $cars[$index] ?: end($cars) ?>
```

But note this will generate an E_NOTICE if the $index element does not exist. To avoid the notice, you'd need something like:

```
<?= isset($cars[$index]) ? $cars[$index] : end($cars) ?>
```